How to Loop through elements in post to create navigation
I want to loop through elements (headers) in post and add them to navigation section.
Similar to how minima template loops through posts
{% for item in site.posts %}
    <li {% if page.url contains item.url %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

But catch all h1 and h2 tags in a post.
Is it possible? How would I do that?

That is a statement. What is your question?

The question is...Is it possible? How would I do that?

Then rewrite your title and body into that question and not here in the comments.

@So_nm I might be wrong, but I don't think Jekyll has something like that built-in. You could of course parse the markdown to an AST with some markdown library, then traverse that AST to extract all the headings.

Steps for inspecting site.posts:
Copy contents (all 3 lines) below into ./assets/site.json
---
---
{{site|jsonify}}

Then go to 127.0.0.1/yoursite/assets/site.json and view the structure of site.posts - hopefully that will help with your problem!
